# waitAction(Duration) in Appium is not working

Tags: android, action, appium, long-press

I'm working on an Action, were I have to longpress a webelement to get `contextMenu`.

- Below is my sample piece of code:

  ```
  TouchAction t = new TouchAction(driver);t.press(driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='People Names']")).waitAction(3000).release() .perform();
  ```

But strangely, the waitAction(Duration) is not working.

The error says "The method `waitAction(Duration)` in the type `TouchAction` is not applicable for the `arguments (int)`"

Answer (score 0):

try using
`t.longPress(driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='People Names']")).release().perform();`

I also added the latest Appium Client Library for Java (selenium-java-3.6.0)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code, Duration class having a different function for ms, second, min, etc. Below code uses 3000 ms waiting time

```
    TouchAction t =new TouchAction(driver);

    t.press(
       driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='People Names']")
    ).waitAction(Duration.ofMillis(3000)).release().perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
TouchAction t = new TouchAction(driver);
t.press(driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='People Names']")).waitAction(Duration.ofMillis(3000)).release().perform();
```

It Works. Just import the duration!!

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
action1.press(X1, Y1).waitAction(java.time.Duration.ofMillis(5000)).release()
```

Comment: Why should he?  Please explain in greater detail how this will solve the problem.